# Realm object as @Published with live value

Tags: ios, swift, realm, combine

I have a class `Service` that contains a property `user` that is a Realm object. This object -it contains the information about the user that uses the app- has to accessed by different classes (`ViewModel`s) that should always have the most recent version of said object as a `@Published` property.
(Since Realm objects are "live" as they say, one could assume the `@Published` property calls the `objectWillChange` automatically when the object is modified, but it does not.)

```swift
class Service: NSObject {
    
    static var shared: Service = Service()
    
    @Published var user: User?

    // realm is opened in RealmService, it is a synced realm ..
    @MainActor
    func loadOrGenerateOwnUser(userId: String) {
        guard let realm = RealmService.shared.realm else {
            print("realm not ready")
            return
        }
        
        if let user = realm.objects(User.self).where( { $0._id == userId } ).first {
            self.user = user
        } else {
            let user = User(_id: userId)
            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(user)
                }
                self.user = user
            } catch {
                print("failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to iOS development, but maybe this could be done using Combine? I see that realm objects have a `.publisher` property, but when doing `.sink` there is no value received, only the completion is run.

This code should update a `@Published` of an `ObservableObject` class with the most recent value of user... this doesn't work at all:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    @Published var user: User?

    init() {
        setupBindings()
    }
    
    func setupBindings() {
        Service.shared.user.publisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { completion in print("Completed with \(completion)") // this is    called once only
                } receiveValue: { [weak self] user in
                    print("----------------test") // this is never called
                    self?.user = user
                }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
     }
}
```

P.S: is there a better way to have user data accessible throughout an entire app? I am unsure if this is a good way of doing it, since I cannot find much information about problems like this..

P.P.S: User object

```swift
class User: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Decodable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: String
    @Persisted var userName: String?
    // more
        
    convenience init(_id: String, userName: String? = nil) {
        self.init()
        self._id = _id
        self.userName = userName
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got `self.user` and `self.ownUser` in the `Service` singleton but there is no `self.ownUser`. Possibly a typo?

Comment: You can directly observe an object for changes using [@ObservedRealmObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/react-to-changes/#observe-an-object) which will invalidate and re-load a view upon object changes. That would guarantee the object and the view is always up-to-date which satisfies the question objective. So it would be simply `@ObservedRealmObject var user: User` Why not use that?

Comment: The problem is I want to abstract the logic associated to all data away from the views and use a `ViewModel` that handles fetching - **in this case** fetching from a singleton, but could be some other way elsewhere in the app. I also see the ViewModel concept is widely used, which gives me some confidence that it could be good practice.